# Why this async method don't cause deadlock on a thread?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, deadlock

I need an explanation why this code doesn't cause deadlock on the thread it's running in
(It's a WinForm application and these happens in button_Click):

```
Task FakeMainThread = Task.Run(async() =>  // fake main thread
{
    async Task asyncMethod()               // executed in FakeMainThread
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>               // 'await'ing in FakeMainThread
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            MessageBox.Show("child Task finished");
            return 3;
        });
        MessageBox.Show("asyncMethod finished");
    }

    asyncMethod().Wait();     // deadlock should appear in FakeMainThread 
    MessageBox.Show("FakeMainThread finished");
    return 4;
});
```

`asyncMethod().Wait();` should block the fakeMainThread Task's thread while it's await another task to finish and since `await` is happening in fakeMainThread too it shouldn't be able to 'await' and deadlock should appear on fakeMainThread. But it doesn't happen and I see bot `MessageBox.Show("asyncMethod finished");` and `MessageBox.Show("FakeMainThread finished");` messages.
Note: if I put this:

```
async Task asyncMethod()               
{
    await Task.Run(() =>              
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        MessageBox.Show("child Task finished");
        return 3;
    });

    MessageBox.Show("asyncMethod finished");
}

asyncMethod().Wait();          // deadlock appears in Main Thread (UI)
MessageBox.Show("FakeMainThread finished");
```

in main button1_click() inside directli deadlock appears on UI.   Thanks!

Comment: why should a thread-pool thread that isn't "await"-ing (it is just calling `Wait()`) deadlock? it isn't touching the UI thread (via sync-context), so you're not blocking that - why would it care?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't experience a deadlock in the first code example because of the `SynchronizationContext`. This context says what the await must do to restore your code. When you start a new task (`Task.Run`), you will get the default context. In the `button1_click` you get the context from the form.

The context for the form allows to execute only a single thread (the one used to paint/update your form).

When you call `.Wait()`, then you keep that thread 'locked' with waiting until the task is done. That means that the thread is not released for another job and this is one of the reasons that the form goes into the 'not responding' state.

When you do an `await [code]`, and that code is done, then it will ask the synchronization context to schedule the remainder of the code.

- In case of the default context, any free thread is taken and your code will continue, the task is marked as done, and thus the 'loop' in the `.Wait()` gets signaled that the task is done and continues.
- In case of the forms context, there is only a single thread, thus the completion of this task is scheduled to run after the current code is done. This is the reason of the deadlock.

Avoiding this deadlock is the main reason that you most often get the suggestion to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, this tells the `await` that it should substitute the current synchronization context with the default one, thus allowing you to use any free thread.
The only reason you don't want to use this (or say `ConfigureAwait(true)`) is if you need to update something on your form (WPF or WinForms) or you need your http context (ASP.NET, not ASP.NET Core). This is because only a single thread has access to your form or http context. Here you don't get an exception on your `MessageBox.Show` because this is 'outside' of the forms context and doesn't need this special thread/synchronization context.

See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/ for more information.

Comment: "*When you call .Wait(), then you basically ask your code to run a constant loop*" <== AFAIK this is not correct. The `Task.Wait` is not a [busy wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). It uses a `ManualResetEventSlim` [internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs.html#959427ac16fa52fa), which in turn, after doing a little spinning, uses the `Monitor.Wait` method to block the current thread.

Comment: That is why I have noted "simplified, there is a bit more to it than just this". This is an implementation detail, the result is the same except that it's more performant and what I said is maybe easier to grasp for some, but thank you for the further explanation :)

Comment: Honestly I don't think that a misleading explanation is worthy, even if it's easier to grasp. Anyone who doesn't know how waiting works, and takes your answer as a source of information, will learn something that will later have to unlearn. I would suggest to remove this problematic part from your otherwise good answer.